# Deactivate .apk in Open Testing

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in the process of fixing a Policy violation and have been updating the app and submitting changes for review.

My fixes keep getting rejected because there is an old .apk version in the Open Testing track. Play support told me to Deactivate the old .apk but I can't find a way to do that (and now they don't respond to my emails).

I did upload a newer version into the Open Testing track but since the new one is not getting approved, the appeal keeps coming back as "rejected" specifically because of the old version .apk which is still there.

Does anyone know how to Deactivate an old .apk in the Open Testing track?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your new App Bundle with a different version code in open testing then your old App Bundle is Deactivated automatically I received the same issue I try like this my issue is solved and now my app is live on the play store

Comment: I already did that - the appeal keeps coming back rejected specifically because of the old .apk that would deactivate. Does it make sense? No.